# Interresting way to quadrangulate faces. Can it be done in Blender?

Tags: modeling, scripting, faces, topology, subdivision-surface

I have problem converting triangulated faces to quads on complex meshes. "Tris to Quads" option rarely produce any good results. When I searched web for other solutions I have found [this rather strange hack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eR3F7tAS9E) in 3ds Max, which even have been simplified to short [script/macro here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Navlv3PvMCA). 
So i decided to give it a try. 
And here are the results:

Oryginal mesh:
[image: Oryginal mesh] 
Tris To Quads result (topology flow is messed up):
[image: Tris To Quads result]
Hack result imported back to Blender:
[image: Hack method, model imported back to Blender]

So the 3ds Max hack produce almost perfect results! Topology is clear and almost all edge loops are preserved. 
It would be nice to write similar script in Blender, but seems that this "Poly Bomb" is rather complex tool and I can't find any equivalent in Blender.

Example mesh to test with:
[image]

Comment: The 3ds script is on [link from youtube vid](https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/convert-a-triangulated-mesh-into-quads-using-quadrangulate--cg-21606) which may shed some light.  Don't have 3ds to test.

Comment: I have used this script in 3ds Max demo. But it internally uses Max integrated "Mesh Bomb" tool. So whole point is: how does this tool actually works.

Comment: try googling "quadrangulate algorithm"  Quite likely with the algo, the script can be written.